# Hide the keyboard in autoComplete

Tags: java, android

I would like to slide the autoComplete list up/down to hide the keyboard, I tried this code, but it didn't work:

```
 autoCompleteCliente.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {             

    esconderTeclado(getActivity());

     return true;
        }
    });

    public void esconderTeclado(Activity activity){
            View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
            if(view != null){
                InputMethodManager manager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                manager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0 );
            }
        }
```

Does anyone have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Define which action you want to catch, this is the example when the finger touch is up / leaving the view

```
autoCompleteCliente.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                  esconderTeclado(getActivity());
             }
             return true;
      }
});
```

Comment: So I would like a similar action, however for when I move the autoComplete list up or down